# Hashmaps sell plane tickets java

Tags: java, hashmap, ticket-system

I'm doing a project for university of an app that sells flight tickets.
in the part of offering the plane seats available,I'm making them with hashmaps, putting the passenger name, and the row & seat as the key.
I don´t know how to use the scanner to ask the client to write down the row and seat he wants, and to mark the seat as occupied. Shall I create a class called seat? if you have some idea I would be very thankful.

```
public AsientosConNombre(Integer row, String seat) {
        super(row, seat);
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nombrePasajero = Scanner.getString("Enter your name: ");
    Seat1 asientopasajero= new Seat1(AsientosConNombre);

    //creo el hashmap
    HashMap<Seat1, String> Asientos = new HashMap<Seat1, String>();
    //llenamos el hashmap con la informacion ingresada por el pasajero.

    Asientos.put(asientopasajero, nombrePasajero );

    //esto deberia devolver la app clientes cuando el usuario indica su nombre para saber su vuelo.
    // (ademas del horario y fecha del vuelo)
    System.out.println("Your information: "+ Asientos);
}
```

and the other class I made is:

```
public class Seat1  {
    Integer row = Scanner.getInt("Enter your row: ");
    String seat = Scanner.getString("Enter your seat: ");
    public Seat1(Integer row, String seat) {
        this.row = row;
        this.seat = seat;
    }
    public boolean full(boolean occupied){
        return occupied;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what this code is doing is that it is using your seat object as a key and is storing the name as a value. You should be storing the seat such as it's row and seat number as the key and as a value you could set the flag which would tell if that seat is occupied. 
So whenever you would create a seat you would put true in the hashmap with that key(seat number, row, name) and whenever a new client requests the same key you can see if the seat is occupied or not.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
Integer row = Scanner.getInt("Enter your row: ");
String seat = Scanner.getString("Enter your seat: ");
```

needs to be in a code block, it can not just sit there where you define your fields.

Try moving in to your `main` method

```
Integer row = Scanner.getInt("Enter your row: ");
String seat = Scanner.getString("Enter your seat: ");
```

and then use these field to create your `Seat`

```
Seta myseat = new Seat (row, seat);
```